# Can't zoom on u3d object in pdf

Tags: pdftex, pdf, 3d, media9, zooming

I am trying to make pdfs with u3d objects embedded, however when doing so I note that I cannot zoom in on the object, either by scrolling, or switching to the zoom tool. Interestingly, the pan tool also does not work. If, for example, I read a pdf with a u3d object embedded from elsewhere, e.g. from the media9 guide, or from creation directly in Solidworks, the zoom works fine, so it seems to be something in the LaTeX that is wrong.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\includemedia[label=frame,width=0.8\linewidth,height=0.5\linewidth,activate=pageopen,3Dtoolbar,3Dmenu]{}{octagon.u3d}

\end{document}
```

The u3d file can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4b0709v0lrjzbdr/octagon.U3D

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: TeX doesn't know anything about u3d. It treats the u3d file as a blackbox while embedding it. All interaction is handled by the PDF Reader (Adobe Reader). There must be some peculiarity with the u3d file. Can you make it available for download somehow?

Comment: Edited to include link to u3d file.

Comment: Which pdf viewer are you using?

Comment: Adobe reader (latest version). I have also just noticed a work around - if I right click and choose 'part options', 'fit visible', I can zoom afterwards.

Comment: I think I have found an answer: one has to define an initial viewpoint in the media9 options for it to work properly. E.g. the following code now works well: \includemedia[
width=0.6\linewidth,
height=0.6\linewidth,
activate=pageopen,
3Daac=60.000000,
3Dcoo=0.037 -0.0012 0.060,
3Dc2c=0.841 0.058 0.538,
3Droo=0.25,
3Droll=94.97]{}{octagon.u3d}

Comment: A good first camera setting is obtained via the *Generate Default View* context menu entry.

Answer (score 1):

A default camera setting is required. To get good options for `\includemedia`, follow instructions (Sect. 7.2 3D quick-start guide) in the `media9` documentation.

First, insert the [3D file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4b0709v0lrjzbdr/octagon.U3D) without camera settings, yet providing option `3Dmenu` as
 follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
  width=0.5\linewidth,
  height=0.5\linewidth,activate=pageopen,
  3Dtoolbar,
  3Dmenu,
]{}{octagon.U3D}

\end{document}
```

Then, open the PDF in A-Reader, right-click on the 3D widget and select *Generate Default View* from the context menu. This will centre the 3D object 
in the view-port and print the corresponding camera settings to the console. Copy and paste these settings to the option list of `\includemedia`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
  width=0.5\linewidth,
  height=0.5\linewidth,activate=pageopen,
  3Dtoolbar,
  3Dmenu,
  3Dcoo=0.03645917773246765 -0.0012150183320045471 0.06018916517496109,
  3Droo=0.4712926502989337,
  3Dlights=Headlamp,
]{}{octagon.U3D}

\end{document}
```

Finally close the PDF, re-compile the document and re-open the PDF in A-Reader. Now, you will be able to manipulate (zoom, rotate, show/hide parts of) the 3D object.